# How do I query mongodb with an array of IDs

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

This is golang.
My problem is in the collection search by IDs

I want to find several collections with an array of IDs

This is the document

```
/*document with name brands*/
{
    first_id : "100"
    second_id : "200"
    name : "adidas",
    description: "clothing"
}
{
    first_id : "101"
    second_id : "202"
    name : "ferrari",
    description: "auto"
}
```

This is the collection model

```
type Brand struct {
    FirstID     string  `bson:"first_id" json:"first_id"`
    SecondID    string  `bson:"second_id" json:"second_id"`
    Name        *string `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    Description *string `bson:"description" json:"description"`
}
```

This function performs the search by IDs, here is the problem

```
func searchByID(collection *mongo.Collection) {

ids := [][]string{{"100", "200"}, {"101", "202"}}

filter2 := bson.M{"first_id,second_id": ids} // This is the problem

cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), filter2)

brands := []Brand{}
if err == nil {
    for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
        brand := Brand{}
        cursor.Decode(&brand)
        brands = append(brands, brand)
    }
} else {
    print(err.Error())
}

print("print the brands")
print(brands) //Result []

}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and query which you already tried

Comment: ok

I have already rethought the question

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
filter2 := map[string]interface{}{
"first_id":  map[string]interface{}{"$in": []string{"100", "200"}},
"second_id": map[string]interface{}{"$in": []string{"101", "202"}},}
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), interface{}(filter2))
```

Comment: It is not the right solution.
That's the same as

filter2 := bson.M{"first_id": bson.M{"$in": []string{"100", "200"}}, 
            "second_id": bson.M{"$in": []string{"101", "202"}}
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), filter2)